# Converting between Int32 and enum

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a custom type called `ScaleGroup`. I am trying to parse out the data (done) then convert it to ScaleGroup for comparison. ScaleGroup is an `enum`. I found this method online of conversion but it not working. How can I get the conversion?

Here is my type declaration

```
public ScaleGroup ScaleGroup { get; set; }
```

Here is where I need it to change from an `Int32` to `ScaleGroup`

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(ld.ScaleGroup);
int secondDigit = num % 10;
ld.ScaleGroup = (ScaleGroup)Convert.ChangeType(
       secondDigit, typeof(ScaleGroup));//problem spot
```

`ScaleGroup` declaration:

```
public enum ScaleGroup
{
    GROUP_1 = 1,
    GROUP_2 = 2,
    BOTH = 3
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `Convert.ChangeType`, why don't you just provide a constructor for `ScaleGroup` which takes an `int` parameter?

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't think about it since I was parsing

Comment: @JonSkeet How would one do that in a reader?

Comment: Well you're parsing, but then you've got an `int`, so anything after that point doesn't need to do any parsing... It's not clear what you mean by "in a reader"

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought the secondDigit was the only parsing there? the other is conversion

Comment: My mistake - but your question isn't really clear. What do you mean by "since I was parsing" then? What is `secondDigit`? `And why do you need `Convert.ToInt32` at all? Why doesn't `ScaleGroup` provide a property which gives you an `int`? It would really help us if you'd tell us more about `ScaleGroup`.

Comment: @JonSkeet edit has been made

Comment: Oh, you hadn't mentioned that it's an enum. Indeed, you claimed it's a class - but it's not. Just cast...

Comment: @JonSkeet Seconddigit is for numbers bigger than 9 so 44 I need 4

Comment: I've changed title/post to match "enum" vs. "class" confusion between your post and sample favoring "enum" - feel free to rollback. Side note: please try to avoid ALL_CAPS in the class/member/enum names and generally follow default CamalCase coding guideline for C# in public samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we know that `ScaleGroup` *isn't* a class, but an enum, it's simple:

```
int num = (int) ld.ScaleGroup;
int secondDigit = num % 10;
ld.ScaleGroup = (ScaleGroup) secondDigit;
```

(It's not clear to me that that's actually what you want, given your enum declaration, but that will perform the relevant conversions...)

Comment: That did it! My colleague made this enum in simple terms what is it for?

Comment: You should ask your colleague what it's for... I have no idea what you're doing.